# How do I get the src_small url from an FQL Query with the object_id returned after uploading an image my facebook profile via javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello I have tried several resources now but can't seem figure out how to return the src_small url after posting an image to facebook via javascript. I'm getting the object_id as a response and then I'm trying to perform and FQL query to get the small and large url....the upload function executes fine, then the fql query doesn't return anything. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
 function uploadphoto() {
var imgURL = "img_URL";

FB.api('me/photos', 'post', {
    url: imgURL, message: 'Pura Vita'
}, function (response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
        alert(response.error);

    } else {
        alert(response.id);
        getPhotoInfo(response.id); 
    }
});
```

}

```
function getPhotoInfo(oid) {
    FB.api(
        {
            method: 'fql.query',
            query: 'Select src_big,src_small from photo where aid in(SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = me()) and object_id =' + '"' + oid + '"'
        },
        function (response) {
            alert('Post url: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
        });
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more hour and I realized I didn't have the correct permissions set!